# Jemmy: call JButtonOperator.pushNoBlock()

Tags: java, jbutton, jemmy

Jemmy question:
Does `pushNoBlock()` method of the class JButtonOperator **really** call the corresponting jButtonActionPerformed method of JButton, or it is just the GUI - click, without running into jButtonActionPerformed?
It seems, it does not go into the method, so anyone knows how to test real functionality?

Comment: I am not familiar with Jemmy, but my own guess would be that something like this would push the button itself, since GUI components can have multiple listeners, and it would be much simpler to wire this tool to simply push the button.  But having said this, wouldn't a GUI click call all the button's listeners by default?

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels In my test i try following:  i set a break-point into jButtonActionPerformed, while simple running the test, it does not stops there (so it does not comes into jButtonActionPerformed. If i set some break-point  before, click on button **manually** and continue debug, it **does** stops in jButtonActionPerformed. So i guess it does not. The questions is also how to do "real click" on button, to test real functionality?

Comment: Per [Jemmy Documentation](https://jemmy.java.net/tutorial.html#nonblocking): `"For instance, button puching is performed by ButtonDriver implementation, which has press, release and push methods. The implementation could do pushing using mouse, keyboard, or just invoke AbstractButton.doClick() method. - See more at: https://jemmy.java.net/tutorial.html#nonblocking"`. So it looks to be actually having the button pushed.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels, Liars!!! Tested again: pushNoBlock() does **NOT** go even inside jButtonActionPerformed, while **push()** does, howewer now it is the anoter problem that it does not go inside the runnable there, called with REquestProcessor.post() (of cource, breakpoints in run() are set). Howewer, it is another question...